# Solang anchor commands after "anchor init <name> --solidity" yields "Error: No such file or directory (os error 2)"

Tags: anchor, solang

To reproduce:

```
anchor init <name> --solidity
anchor build
# output: Error: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

I have tried many logging options but none showed any relevant information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what combination of solana/anchor versions I had but reinstalling the stable one with:

```
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/stable/install)"
```

Did the trick.